# Rigid Body and cell fracture acting weird after the first frame

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, modifiers

I'm making an animation, im using cell fracture. I have something that will get smashed later in the animation.This is what it should look like:
[image]
That is frame one. When I go to frame 2, it looks like this:
[image]

it wasn't like that before but now it is for some reason.

Here is the .blend file (If you need it):
https://bit.ly/2Ot3jTl

The animation has a car smashing through a wall. The rigid body still works fine:
[image]
But the wall looks like that.

I don't know why it's doing that, please help.
Thanks
Daniel

Comment: Looks like the location of the rigid bodies got reset, sometimes it happens due to the finicky nature of rigid bodies. Make sure their origins are in the right place, and see if you can reset their locations back to 0 if that puts them in the right spot again. Also try resetting the rigid body frames under the scene properties above the red world properties button.

Comment: I fixed it by deleting the bakes, I did it before and it didn't work. But this time it did.